# Proving transitivity of big-omega and big-theta notations

Tags: asymptotics

I am trying to understand mathematical proofs and their applications to big-omega $\Omega$ and big-theta $\Theta$ notations.

The first one is transitivity:

$f \in O(g) \; and \; g \in O(h) \Rightarrow f \in O(h)$

I am having a lot of trouble with this and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Follow the definitions of big-O and big-Omega

Comment: Hint: $f<c\cdot g$ and $g<d\cdot h$ imply $f<c\cdot d\cdot h$.